# Finding screen elements in appium(iOS) using contains

Tags: python, ios, automated-tests, appium

I am doing QA and recently started using appium and cucumber to automate some tests and am still new to this.

I succeeded in what I wanted to automate using some functions like this one.

```
def function(element_name)
    find_element(:xpath,
                 '//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name="' + element_name + '"]'
                ).click
end
```

This works for what I want, but now I am trying to redo the same functions but using `contains`. Something like this

```
def function(element_name)
  find_element(:xpath,
               '//*[contains(text(), element_name)]'
              ).click
end
```

What I'm getting is

> An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

I think I am just not using `contains` the right way but I am really not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Xpath** is not a good way for searching elements in Appium/XCUITest as it is often *too slow* and might not work as you expect it to work (your case with contains).

Instead you should you try XCUITest native locator strategies: **iOSNsPredicate** or **iOSClassChain**, e.g.

```
driver.find_element_by_ios_predicate("label contains 'Some text'")
```

You can check more examples here: [python client tests](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/master/test/functional/ios/find_by_ios_predicate_tests.py), [java client tests](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory_tests/XCUITModeTest.java)

Comment: Thank you, I remember reading somewhere else that using Xpath to locate elements was a bad idea but I was having a hard time finding better strategies. Right now I managed to start using predicate but I'm still trying to  figure out how to get `contains` to work. Do you know any good resources to explore about strategies to use?

Comment: I already provided an example of using contains text in predicate expression (see my answer: <attr> contains <text>). To read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate . I suggest to use Appium-desktop as you can check predicate/chain strategy while inspecting your app. But more useful is to check code examples that I mentioned as Appium may not handle every expression you will provide

Answer (score 0):

the way you are using contains is correct, the only problem is its not finding the element. 
If XPATH is not working , why dont you try with relative path e.g. below

```
def function(element_name)
  //tbody//td[contains(text(),element_name)]
```